# How do I solve this procedure and functions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this home work question and I don't know what I am doing wrong there are a lot of errors which I don't know how to correct. This the question:

An automative service shop performs the following services (all the services below are assigned a value):

- Oil Change
- Lube Job
- Radiator flush
- Transmision flush inspection
- Muffler replacement and
- Tire rotation

Create an application that displays the total for a customer's visit. This is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    'class level declerations
    Const decTax_Rate As Decimal = 0.06D ' TaX on Parts only
    Const decOilChange As Decimal = 26   ' cost of oil change
    Const decLubeJob As Decimal = 18     ' cost for lube job
    Const decRadiator As Decimal = 30    ' cost for Raditor Flush
    Const decTransmission As Decimal = 80 ' cost of transmission work
    Const decInspection As Decimal = 15   ' cost of inspection
    Const decReplaceMuffler As Decimal = 100 'cost of replacing muffler
    Const decRotateTire As Decimal = 20   'cost of rotating tire

End Class

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(....) Handles btnCalculate.Click ( Error: Identify expected. I put in the following identifiers( Byval decpart as decimal and so on) but still underline the whole procedure as statement is not valid in a namespace)
    ' The procedure calculate the service total
    Dim decPart As Decimal            ' hold charges for parts
    Dim decServiceLabor As Decimal    ' hold charges for labor and other services
    Dim decTaxCharges As Decimal      ' hold sales tax on parts
    Dim decTotalCharges As Decimal    ' hold total charges


    decServiceLabor = OilLubeCharges() + FlushCharges() + MiscCharges() + OtherCharges()
    decPart = part1
    decTaxCharges = CalcTax(decParts)
    decTotalCharges = decOtherCharges + decTaxCharges

    lblServiceString.Text = decServiceLabor.ToString("c")
    lblParts.Text = decPart.ToString("c")
    lblPartsTax.Text = decTax_Rate.ToString("c")
    lblTotalFees.Text = decTotalCharges.ToString("c")
End Sub
Private Sub btnClear_Click(...) Handles btnClear.Click

    ' This procedur clears the controls to default values
    ClearOilLube()  ' Clear the check boxes for oil and Lube jobs
    ClearFlushes()  ' Clear the check boxes for radiation and transmission
    ClearsMisc()    ' Clear the check boxes for inspection muffler and tire
    ClearOther()    ' Clear the text boxes for parts and labor
    ClearFees()     ' Clear the summary lables

End Sub
Private Sub btnExit_Click(...) Handles btnExit.Click
    ' Close the form.
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Function OilLubeCharges(ByVal decOilChange As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' This function returns the charges for an oil change and or lube job.
    Dim decOilLube As Decimal = 0D
    If chkOilChange.Checked = True Then
        decOilLube += decOilChange
    End If

    If chkLubeJob.Checked = True Then
        decOilLube += decLubeJob
    End If
    Return decOilLube
End Function


Function MiscCharges(ByVal decInspection As Decimal) As Decimal
    'The function returns the total charges for an inspection, muffler replacement and/or a tire rotation
    Dim decMisc As Decimal = 0D
    If chkInspection.Checked = True Then
        decMisc += decInspection
    End If

    If chkReplaceMuffler.Checked = True Then
        decMisc += decReplaceMuffler
    End If

    If chkTireRotation.Checked = True Then
        decMisc += decRotateTire

    End If

    Return decMisc
End Function


Function FlushCharges(ByVal decRadiator As Decimal) As Decimal
    'This function return the total charges for a radiator flush and/or a tansmission flush
    Dim decFlush As Decimal = 0D
    If chkRadiatorFlush.Checked = True Then
        decFlush += decRadiator

    End If

    If chkTrasmission.Checked = True Then
        decFlush += decTransmission

    End If

    Return decFlush

End Function
Function Parts(ByVal decpart As Decimal) As Decimal
    '  To hold the parts sales
    Dim decPart1 As Decimal
    decPart1 += decpart

    Return decPart1


End Function
Function CalcTax(ByVal decpart As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' This Function receives the sales part and returns the sale part tax.
    Return decpart * decTax_Rate
End Function

Sub ResetOil()
    ' This procedure resets the oil and lube job.
    chkOilChange.Checked = False
    chkLubeJob.Checked = False
End Sub
Sub ResetMisc()
    ' This procedure resets the misc
    chkInspection.Checked = False
    chkReplaceMuffler.Checked = False
    chkTireRotate.Checked = False
End Sub
Sub ResetFlushFluids()
    ' This procedure resets the flush
    chkRadiatorFlush.Checked = False
    chkTrasmission.Checked = False
End Sub
Sub ResetPrice()
    ' This procedure resets the price
    lblServiceString.Text = String.Empty
    lblParts.Text = String.Empty
    lblPartsTax.Text = String.Empty
    lblTotalFees.Text = String.Empty

End Sub
```

Actually all the first line of the functions were underlined as invalid namespace statements and all the procedures need identifiers even after I put in an Identify. There weren't any errors in the class form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The very first thing you should do after typing the word "error" is to start typing the **exact** error you're getting, including any error messages. You're expecting people to guess what's not working and what the errors might be. We're more than happy to help you find a solution for your homework problem, but we're not going to do it for you. Please edit your question to indicate what exact errors you're getting, and if they're related to specific code indicate (with comments) which lines are causing the error. It will help you get an answer more quickly. Thanks. :)

Comment: We're not going to just do your homework for you.  Ask a specific question about one of your bugs and you'll be more likely to get an answer.  By the looks of it, this could turn into you asking a few questions.

Answer (score 0):

For Starters you need to make sure that your `Button` events and `Functions` are part of your `Form1` Class.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it worked somehow, but it say this now: "handles clause requres a withEvent variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types" on the btnCalculate button. how do I write the WithEvent type.

Comment: @user1239164  Are you creating your buttons programically? Then your definition should be something like this ` Dim WithEvents btnCalculate As New Button'

Comment: @user1239164 I am also making the assumption that you have only one form `Form1` and your buttons are on that `Form`.